# Trouble with Timeout function and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I get the following Javascript error when calling goon() within a jquery function. I thought it is defined...but obviously not...?! Why not?:

> **goon is not defined var timeout= setTimeout('goon()', 3000)**;

```
    $('.rs-slideshow').stop().fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft:$offset
        }, 1000, function(){
                function goon(){
                    $('.rs-slideshow').fadeIn('fast');
                    $('#slideshow').clearQueue().rsfSlideshow('startShow');
                }
                var timeout= setTimeout('goon()', 3000);

        });
    });
```

Comment: That's because the string `'goon()'` is evaluated in global scope and your function is not accessible in global scope, it is only local to the animation callback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function is undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804112/function-is-undefined)

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for the comment...how can i change it that its working? mark them as private?

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted as duplicate or the answer by @m90.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a String (`'goon()'` as delimited by the `'`s) to your `setTimeout` which is evaluated in **global scope**. The function though is not accessible in global scope, it is only **local** to the animation callback, hence it cannot be found.

Pass the reference directly instead:

```
var timeout= setTimeout(goon, 3000);
```

Note that I also omitted the `()` as this would not pass the function but execute the function and pass its returned value.

Comment: Passing a string to `setTimeout()` is allowed, although not recommended. The passed string is `eval()`'d.

Comment: @Juhana: It is allowed, but it's the source of the problem here, so passing the function reference directly solves the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling feel free to edit my answer btw, since I didn't know that function names passed as Strings will be evaluated in global scope and I don't want to add any gibberish. Learn something new every day.